# anndroid test fail java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider androidx.startup.InitializationProvider

Tags: gradle, terminal, android-jetpack-compose, android-testing, app-startup

I'm trying to run android tests from the terminal(gradlew connectedAndroidTest), all tests run and pass successfully, but at the end of the i'm filing with an errorTest run failed to complete. Instrumentation run failed due to Process crashed.

I am use jetpack compose and junit

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider androidx.startup.InitializationProvider: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f10002b

```
junit:junit:4.13.2
androidx.test:core:1.5.0
androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.5.3
androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:1.5.3
androidx.test:runner:1.5.0
agp = 8.2.2
compileSdk = 34
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()
}
testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"I tried allocating more memory to the emulator, but it didn't help.
```

Comment: I tried allocating more memory to the emulator, but it didn't help.

Comment: When I run tests through android studio using the green run test button, there are no problems.
I don't use the Startup library https://developer.android.google.cn/jetpack/androidx/releases/startup, but Is implementing a transitive from work manager

Comment: Doesn't work for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65321223/unable-to-get-provider-androidx-startup-initializationprovider